# Instagram API - Read pictures with custom hashtag javascript

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I'm learning to use Instagram API. I need to show all pictures with a specific hashtag from Javascript. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any sample code to share with the community?

Comment: I have found some examples with PHP or other server side languages. I need it running on client side. I cannot find neither any documentation from instagram for this kind of stuff

Comment: You cannot make the query from client side due to CORS restrictions, you still need to set up a server API to request the instagram API with credentials generated by client side instagtam sdk

Comment: I have posted my aswer below, using jsonp, it is working from client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution for me:

I generate the `access token` here: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

and then by ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<meta-tag>/media/recent?access_token=44757144.1677ed0.18f9b45ff1ea4231931d1d7ab5557833',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(result){
        if(result.meta.code == 200){
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: User access token has expiry perioud, and this token is for you only, not for all instagram users, so unless you plan to redirect the user to that website to grab their token, u need to load a instagram sdk on ur website

Comment: I dont need to get user info, I just need to get pictures of some hashtag, so it does not matter which user id is using

Answer (score 0):

There is no instagram API for hashtag search, however there are some workarounds. You can

```js
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashTag + '/media/recent?client_id=' + config.client_id
```

you can use this API to query all pictures with defined **single** tag. For a collection of hashtags you can make separate query and then combine the result based on the document ids.

More info about media API https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Comment: Yes, I found that. But I cannot make a ajax call cross domain to get that, can I?

Comment: And, for the client ID, does not have the user to accept any form? What if the user does not have an instagram account, I cannot show any pictures?

Comment: If you talking about back end javascript no user access token is required to extract those public media endpoints, generally client id should be enough (you need to create an app at instagram) .

Comment: If you want to crawl media posts for particular user you still need to set up a server API, use instagram sdk to query for user credentials and pass those to your back e d

Comment: A form is generated by sdk, as well as the oauth 1.1 or 2  authentication procedure

Comment: @Yerken, yes there is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search